# Determine the matrix representation for an operator written as an outer product

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

> Suppose $|v_{i} \rangle$ is an orthonormal basis for an inner product space $V$. What is the matrix representation for the operator $|v_{j}\rangle \langle v_{k}|$, with respect to the $|v_{i}\rangle$ basis?

Any hint with this is appreciated.

Comment: If $i \neq k$, then $| v_j \rangle \langle v_k | v_i \rangle = | v_j \rangle 0 = 0$. Also, if $i = k$ we get $| v_j \rangle \langle v_k | v_k\rangle = | v_j \rangle$. So the matrix should be a all zeros, with a 1 in the $(j, k)$ place.

Comment: @Joppy Even i reasoned it this way. I don't know how it is the Identity matrix as claimed in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to take $|v_j\rangle\langle v_k|$, apply it to a basis element, write it again as a combination of the basis, and put the coefficients in columns. That is to say, the matrix $(a_{i\ell})$ we're looking for satisfies $|v_j\rangle\langle v_k| (|v_\ell\rangle) = \sum_i a_{i\ell} |v_i\rangle$. We have $$|v_j\rangle\langle v_k|(|v_\ell\rangle) = \langle v_\ell|v_k\rangle\langle v_k| = \delta_{\ell k}\langle v_k| = \langle v_\ell| = \sum_i\delta_{i\ell}| v_i\rangle,$$so the matrix is the identity. This is why in general we:

- have $(f\otimes v)(w) = f(w)v$;
- identify $V^*\cong V$ using the inner product.
- may see this operator as $|v_j\rangle\otimes \langle v_k|$.

Comment: I don't quite follow this step: $|v_j⟩⟨v_k|(|v_ℓ⟩)=⟨v_ℓ|v_k⟩⟨v_k|$

Comment: I believe that is by definition @jpetitte

Comment: @Brofessor How does that follow from the definition? To my knowledge the definition says, $|v_j⟩⟨v_k|(|v_ℓ⟩)=⟨v_k|v_ℓ⟩|v_j⟩$.

Comment: I down voted because I think this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

i wasnt able to write a comment under the comment by @Joppy which i believe is right.

the i-th column of the matrix A is the operator applied to $|v_i\rangle$, so it is $|v_j\rangle\langle v_k|v_i\rangle=\langle v_k|v_i\rangle|v_j\rangle=\delta_{ik}|v_j\rangle$

so everywhere else is $0$ except for the k-th column, and that column is equal to $|v_j\rangle$, which has a $1$ in the j-th entry (j-th entry of the column vector, so j-th row) and $0$ everywhere else. so it is $1$ in $(j, k)$ entry and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: This is not exactly an answer

Comment: @Shailesh i wanted to comment Jamāl to say that the answer resulting the identity matrix is wrong, and Joppy was right; but I wasnt able to comment

Comment: You will need a few points to be able to comment. Not difficult to earn those.

Comment: thank you very much! i will have a look into how to get the points and hopefully i can copy this answer to the comment and delete this answer