# Clarifying Bra-Ket Notation: Orthonormal Bases

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, notation, orthogonality, complete-spaces

I was asked to find the trace of $(A \in M_{n \times n})$, the matrix that can be written in the form:$$A=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r, \, q \, = \, 1}^n (-1)^{r+q}|r \rangle \langle q|$$ where {$|r \rangle$} is an orthonormal basis. I know that $(\langle r |q \rangle =\delta_{r, \, q})$ but I don't know what $(|r \rangle \langle q|)$ truly means! In particular, I know the completeness relation: $$I=\sum_{j=1}^{n} |e_j \rangle \langle e_j|$$ where is again an orthonormal basis; but I also know that not every basis has that property. Instead, it seems the case; in fact the solution gives me: $$\text{tr}(A)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r \, = \, 1}^n (-1)^{r+r}|r \rangle \langle r| = 1$$ Aside from the abuse of notation, I think that the right solution should be: $$\require{cancel}\text{tr}(A)=\text{tr$\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r \, = \, 1}^n (-1)^{r+r}|r \rangle \langle r|\right)$}=\frac{1}{n} \, \text{tr$\left(\sum_{r \, = \, 1}^n \cancel{(-1)^{2r}}|r \rangle \langle r|\right)$} = \frac{1}{n} \, \text{tr$\left(I\right)$}=\frac{1}{\cancel{n}}\cdot \cancel{n}=1$$

At this point what is really unclear to me is the step: $$\left[A=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r, \, q \, = \, 1}^n (-1)^{r+q}|r \rangle \langle q|\right] \longmapsto \left[ \text{tr}(A)= \text{tr$\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r \, = \, 1}^n |r \rangle \langle r|\right)$} \right]$$

**Where has the second sum gone?** (rhow can this step be legitimate?)

---

NOTE) I have already been able to show that such a matrix is idempotent $(A^2 = A)$.

Comment: For an orthonormal basis, $\left|r\right>\left<q\right|$ is a matrix with element $r, q$ equal to $1$ and all other elements equal to $0$. So that sum is equivalently saying that $A_{rq} = (-1)^{r+q}/n$

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{tr}(|r \rangle \langle q|) = \langle q|r\rangle$

Comment: @eyeballfrog According to definition of dyadic product, this apply surely when the basis {$|r \rangle$} is the canonical one, which is the case i'm in agree with you blindly; but, how can this property be that general? It is always true that it holds for any orthonormal basis?

Comment: @BenGrossmann That's a good observation! When i was explicitely evaluate $\operatorname{tr}(|r \rangle \langle q|)$ with the dyadic product definition, i couldn't see the sum of diagonal's elements like a scalar product!

Comment: Yes. It's essentially what it means to *be* orthonormal.

Comment: @eyeballfrog in that case the excercise is fastly solved, since i can directly observe that $A_{rr}=\frac{1}{n}$.. thanks, you are right.. for completeness of information can you provide a source or anything to prove what are you saying? Or it is just a definition?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I see you intended that $\left|r\right>\left<q\right|$ is a matrix with element $r, q$ equal to $1$ and all other elements equal to $0$, only considering its representation wrt the |r\rangle basis.. (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220946/determine-the-matrix-representation-for-an-operator-written-as-an-outer-product).. Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one solution:

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r, q =  1}^n (-1)^{r+q}|r \rangle \langle q| \right] &= 
\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{tr}\left[ \sum_{r, q =  1}^n (-1)^{r+q}|r \rangle \langle q| \right]
\\ & = 
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r, q =  1}^n \operatorname{tr}\left[(-1)^{r+q}|r \rangle \langle q|\right]
\\ & = 
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r, q =  1}^n (-1)^{r+q}\operatorname{tr}\left[|r \rangle \langle q|\right]
\\ & = 
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r, q =  1}^n (-1)^{r+q}\langle q|r\rangle
\\ &= 
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r, q =  1}^n (-1)^{r+q}\delta_{q,r}
 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r =  1}^n (-1)^{r+r} = \frac nn = 1.
\end{align}
$$

---

General proof that $\operatorname{tr}(\langle x| y \rangle) = \langle y | x \rangle$: first, we need a definition of trace in bra-ket notation. For a finite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ and an operator $A : \mathcal H \to \mathcal H$, we define the trace of $A$ to be the quantity
$$
{\rm tr}(A) = \sum_{r=1}^n \langle r|A|r \rangle
$$
I claim that this quantity is the same regardless of which orthonormal basis is chosen. Indeed, suppose that $|\psi_1\rangle,\dots,|\psi_n\rangle$ is another orthonormal basis.  It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n \langle \psi_r|A|\psi_r \rangle &= 
\sum_{r=1}^n \left\langle \psi_r\left|\left(\sum_{s=1}^n |s\rangle \langle s|\right) A \left(\sum_{t = 1}^n |t\rangle \langle t|\right)\right|\psi_r \right\rangle
\\ & = 
\sum_{r,s,t = 1}^n \langle \psi_r | s \rangle \langle s|A|t \rangle \langle t | \psi_r \rangle
\\ & = 
\sum_{r,s,t = 1}^n \langle t | \psi_r \rangle \langle \psi_r | s \rangle \langle s|A|t \rangle 
\\ & = 
\sum_{s,t = 1}^n \left \langle t \left |\sum_{r = 1}^n |\psi_r \rangle \langle \psi_r| \right| s \right \rangle \langle s |A| t\rangle 
\\ & = \sum_{s,t = 1}^n \langle t|s \rangle \langle s |A| t\rangle 
= \sum_{s = 1}^n \langle s|A|s \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(A).
\end{align}
$$
With that, it is easy to see that for any $|x\rangle,|y\rangle$, we have $\operatorname{tr}(|x \rangle \langle y |) = \langle y|x \rangle$. First, we note that in the case that $|x \rangle$ is the zero-vector, this holds trivially. For the case that $|x \rangle$ is non-zero, construct an orthonormal basis $|\psi_1\rangle,\dots,|\psi_n\rangle$ such that $\psi_1$ is parallel to $|x \rangle$. That is, we have $|\psi_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\langle x|x \rangle}}|x \rangle$, and $\langle \psi_r|x \rangle = 0$ for $r \neq 1$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}(|x \rangle \langle y |) &= \sum_{r = 1}^n \langle \psi_r |x \rangle \langle y|\psi_r \rangle 
\\ & = \langle \psi_1|x\rangle \langle y| \psi_1 \rangle
\\ & = \left[\frac 1{\sqrt{\langle x|x\rangle}}\right]^2 \langle x|x \rangle \langle y|x \rangle = \langle y| x \rangle,
\end{align}
$$
which is what we wanted.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but i would like to discuss about two things.. i will post an answer since the characters limit.

Comment: @guiliolib I am implying that $\text{tr($|r \rangle\langle q|$)} = \langle q|r \rangle  = \delta_{q,r}$; perhaps that is what you meant

Comment: @giuliolib The equation that the book shows is definitely a typo. $|r\rangle \langle r|$ is an operator, which means that the right hand side is a sum of operators, but ${\rm tr}(A)$ should be a scalar (i.e. a number)

Comment: yes, that is, but i wanted to emphatize the $\langle r|r \rangle$ to be more similar to the book's solution..

Comment: ok, i'am finally convinced that the solution in my book has a typo.. thanks

Comment: @giuliolib I don't know of any trick applicable to this problem that is nicer than using the general fact that ${\rm tr}(|x \rangle \langle y|) = \langle y|x \rangle$.

Comment: @giuliolib If you like, there are proofs of the fact that ${\rm tr}(|x \rangle \langle y|) = \langle y|x \rangle$ that don't depend on actually taking the sum of the diagonal of a matrix

Comment: Wow! Such a proof would be great! If it doesn't bother, could you provide it?

Comment: @giuliolib See my latest edit.

Comment: In $\left[  \sum_{r=1}^n \langle \psi_r|A|\psi_r \rangle = \sum_{r=1}^n \left\langle \psi_r\left|\left(\sum_{s=1}^n |s\rangle \langle s|\right) A \left(\sum_{t = 1}^n |t\rangle \langle t|\right)\right|\psi_r \right\rangle \right]$ and $\left[ \sum_{s,t = 1}^n \left \langle t \left |\sum_{r = 1}^n |\psi_r \rangle \langle \psi_r| \right| s \right \rangle \langle s |A| t\rangle = \sum_{s,t = 1}^n \langle t|s \rangle \langle s |A| t\rangle \right]$ are you using the completeness relation?

Comment: If yes, it doesn't it hold for EVERY orthonormal basis(?). Are we using it because we are in $\mathbb{C}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @giuliolib Yes, I'm applying the completeness relation. And yes, the completeness relation works for every orthonormal basis. None of my work requires us to be working in $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb C^n$; note that the trace is defined for an arbitrary linear operator over the finite dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE)** This answer will act as a direct comment to *@BenGrossmann*.

---

I have just two points to discuss about: in your (second-and-third)-last steps are you implying that $\left[ \text{tr($|r \rangle\langle q|$)} = \langle q|r \rangle \delta_{q,r}\right]$? In this case one can omit the sum wrt $(q)$, since the only surviving terms are the ones with $(q=r)$. Still i will remain with: $$\left[ \text{tr($A$)} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^{r+r} \langle r|r \rangle\right] = 1$$ that is different from what the book shows: $$\left[ \text{tr($A$)} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^{r+r} |r \rangle \langle r| \right] = 1$$ Again i think that it is just a typo (and with your answer it seems clearer than ever). What do you think about? The second thing that i want to clarify is if you know some other smart trick to do the job.. maybe something that relies on property of orthonormal basis and bra-ket notation only. Thank you.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I know, and i'm really sorry if this bothered you, but i was searching to replay the answer given by "BenGrossmann", but i encountered the characters limit.. so i thought that post an answer would be a good idea.. if it is not, can you show me another way to add a reply?

Comment: There is a character limit, yes, but nothing prevents you from posting several comments.